# How can I move any file with a certain extension, from one location to another in batch?

Tags: batch-file, move

When I attempt to move a file from one location, I get an error. What I want to do is have the program detect a .PRISON file on the desktop and move that file to a certain directory. I am really new to this and have just figured out very basic commands. This is what I have and it seems not to be working.

```
@echo off
echo "Place your .PRISON files on your Desktop, if they do not move, you need to run the program again"
move /y "%systemdrive%\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\*prison" "%systemdrive%\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Introversion\Prison Architect\saves"
pause
```

Comment: Folder name "Prison Architect" may be cause you the trouble. Try to change folder name to "PrisonArchitect" and modify path in your batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually very close. The problem is that you're using both the %systemdrive% and %userprofile% variables, so the string is starting "C:C:\" instead of just "C:\"

Also, add change *prison to *.prison to grab all files with the prison extension.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was hoping to also do a if/then statement that would tell the user in the CLI that it couldn't detect a file. Maybe even a prompt asking for them to put the file in the search location and to press a button to continue.

Comment: Check out the output of `if /?`, specifically the parts about NOT and EXIST.